# Tree skiing/riding in Colorado

Tags: skiing, snowboarding, colorado

I am getting ready for a Colorado snowboarding trip in a couple of weeks...  YAAAY !!

I have been all over the country and I generally like CO resorts best (Keystone and A-Basin being my favorite), however, one thing I liked better at Heavenly was tree riding, which was absolutely phenomenal.  There were multiple wooded trails and rather nice and steep, just the way I like.  I suppose one thing that made that possible in the Sierras is that the trees were bigger and somewhat more spread apart for that reason than regular evergreens in the Rockies.

I will be mostly around Summit Co. resorts, including the two above mentioned, also Copper, Winter Park etc.

I was looking for ideas on which of the ski areas in the general vicinity and up to an hour away have a good variety of legal (so not off bounds) tree skiing/riding.

**CLARIFICATION:**  What I mean by `tree skiing/riding` is skiing/riding through forested areas, trees presenting an obstacle to dodge

Comment: I would suggest you [edit] your post so it's not asking "what's the best" but instead "where is tree riding available" in Colorado. Questions about "the best" are considered subjective and may be closed. I voted it down for that reason, but if you [edit] it to be less subjective I'd definitely reverse my vote.

Comment: done as per the suggestion

Comment: I know it's not Colorado, but I've always enjoyed the tree skiing in SLC, esp Brighton.

Comment: What is tree riding?

Comment: I had the same query Liam - I originally thought they meant jumping (jibbing?) off trees, but I think they just mean skiing through forested areas.

Comment: yes, what i meant by "tree skiing/riding" is skiing/riding through forested areas, trees presenting an obstacle to dodge

Answer (score 2):

Steamboat has some very nice tree skiing. In general open tree skiing in Colorado involves finding an aspen or similar hardwood grove and those don't occur at the very highest elevations. So as a rough first guess, I'd look for resorts at similar elevations to Steamboat.

I can't think of any similar evergreen groves like those at Heavenly, but it has been 20+ years since I skied Summit County.